# What action when tableview can't dequeue a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I was learning about tableviews the tutorials I followed used the following code-

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Self.reminderListCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ReminderListCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

I just came across example code from Apple which is;

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Self.reminderListCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ReminderListCell else {
        fatalError("Unable to dequeue ReminderCell")
    }
```

What should I implement?  fatalError causes a crash I believe. Is the the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the suggestions. Force unwrap the cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Self.reminderListCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ReminderListCell
```

In practice it causes the same behavior as the `fatalError`.
The code **must not** crash if everything is hooked up correctly. The potential mistake is a design mistake.

The first snippet is pretty silly because in case of the mentioned design mistake nothing will be displayed and you have no idea why.

Force unwrapping is not evil per se.